# A javascript function that receives and returns functions

Tags: javascript, methods

I have a JavaScript function:

```
function oneOf() {
    return arguments[Math.floor(Math.random()*arguments.length)];
}
```

It is designed to take in variable number of arguments and spit out a random one, and this works. I can't get it to take a list of object methods and execute one. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you include the code that isn't working instead of the code that is working?

Comment: Exactly the same way, but you need to invoke it additionally.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001149/how-to-execute-a-method-passed-as-parameter-to-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Insight #1

[`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) allows you to "splat" an array into the arguments list:

```
function sayAll() {
  console.log(arguments);
}

sayAll(1, 2, 3, 4);
// [1, 2, 3, 4]

sayAll.apply(null, ["a", "b", "c"])
// ["a", "b", "c"]
```

#### Insight #2

Functions can be invoked with parenthesis (see above).

Combining these two insights, we get the following:

```
function oneOf() {
  var f = arguments[Math.floor(Math.random()*arguments.length)];
  return f();   // Via insight #2
}

// Via insight #1
oneOf.apply(null, [someFunction, anotherFunction]);
```

If these functions are "methods" on an object and need to retain their `this` context, then we'll need a third insight.

#### Insight #3

[`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) allows creating a function with a fixed `this` context:

```
function sayWhatThisIs() {
  console.log("This is", this);
}

var coolObject = {
  cool: true,
  sayWhat: sayWhatThisIs
};

coolObject.sayWhat();
// This is {cool: true, ...}

oneOf.apply(null, [coolObject.sayWhat.bind(coolObject),
                   sayWhatThisIs.bind(coolObject)]);
// Two variations of binding `sayWhatThisIs` to `coolObject`
```

#### Insight #3a

We could also pass on the `this` context of `oneOf` to [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function oneOf() {
  var f = arguments[Math.floor(Math.random()*arguments.length)];
  return f.apply(this);
}

onOf.apply(coolObject, [coolObject.sayWhat, sayWhatThisIs]);
// Now applying insight #3a to set `onOf`'s `this` context to `coolObject`.
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, could it be because I am calling oneOf() from an object with arguments that are methods of the same object?

Comment: Nope - where `oneOf` is shouldn't matter at all - are you using `bind` or `apply` (from insights 3 / 3a)?