# Using callback's returned value as an argument to another function

Tags: javascript

I have referenced multiple SO questions but I still could not find a solution. These are the questions I took a look at (main ones):

1. [Pass a JavaScript function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter)
2. [How to execute a method passed as parameter to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001149/how-to-execute-a-method-passed-as-parameter-to-function)

**compute.js**:

```
const mainTable = document.getElementById('nonFixedSample');

function getRows(metricName) {
    let row = 0;
    let z = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        if (mainTable.rows[i].firstChild.textContent === metricName) {
            row = i;
            return row;
        }
    }
}

// Here I am trying to pass that function as callback

function stdCellArea(callback) {
    rowNumber = callback();

    let runs = mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells.length;
    // Other code
}
```

Now I am calling it, **reg_report.php**:

```
<script>
    stdCellArea(function() {
        getRows('test');
    });
</script>
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined
>       at stdCellArea (compute.js:17)
>       at reg_report.php:39

Basically, I need to use return value of `getRows()` as an argument for `stdCellArea()`. I know I could simply do this:

```
let x = getRows('text');
stdCellArea(x);
```

But I have to call this function over 10 times, so I do not want to create many variables. Who can help?

Comment: What is the reason that you are doing this with a callback rather than calling `getRows()` directly with something like `let rowNumber = getRows('test');`?

Comment: Actually a very good question. I do not know... I decided to go with callback. What would you use in this case?

Comment: I would replace `rowNumber = callback()` with the code I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: Would there be any difference in performance or any difference at all?

Comment: You should worry about how easy it is to understand the code before you worry about performance. Callbacks are an important tool but don't seem like the correct solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the value from your callback: `return getRows('test');`. Without that, `rowNumber` becomes `undefined` as that's what functions without an explicit `return`, return.

Comment: Wow, I knew it was something as simple as that:) Thanks a lot

Comment: Happens to the best of us!